# 'ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code' despite declaration in header file & c99 flag

Tags: compiler-warnings

I have looked at the related posts and have understood what this error is about.
I'm also relatively new to posting here so please, anything that's wrong with the format let me know.

What I don't understand still is why it is happening in my code. Mind you, some of this code was imported. However it is simple, I've read it through and adjusted it to my design.

I have also tried to add the C99 flag to my makefile but it still returns the error. Maybe I added it wrong?

Thank you for the help!

The warning happens with this line in the main file:

```
graph_p undir_graph = createGraph(example, UNDIRECTED);
```

This is my header file:

```
#define PESO 765
#define MAXLENGTH 50



typedef struct _No {
  char *palavra;
  struct _No *prox;
} No;


typedef struct _Info {
  int m;                        /* dimension of the vector */
  int numPalavras;              /* number of different words  */
  int *num_pal;                 /* hash table hits count */
  int num_comp;                 /* number of comparisons */
  int max_size;         /* size of the biggest list */
  int empty;            /* number of empty lists */
} Info;


typedef No *Hash;               /* typedef for hash table */

typedef enum {UNDIRECTED=0,DIRECTED} graph_type_e;

/* Adjacency list node*/
typedef struct adjlist_node
{
    int vertex;                /*Index to adjacency list array*/
    int weight;                /*Weight of edge to index*/
    struct adjlist_node *next; /*Pointer to the next node*/
}adjlist_node_t, *adjlist_node_p;



/* Adjacency list */
typedef struct adjlist
{
    int num_members;           /*number of members in the list (for future use)*/
    adjlist_node_t *head;      /*head of the adjacency linked list*/
}adjlist_t, *adjlist_p;

/* Graph structure. A graph is an array of adjacency lists.
   Size of array will be number of vertices in graph*/
typedef struct graph
{
    graph_type_e type;        /*Directed or undirected graph */
    int num_vertices;         /*Number of vertices*/
    adjlist_p adjListArr;     /*Adjacency lists' array*/
}graph_t, *graph_p;



void displayGraph(graph_p);
void fillEdges (graph_t *, Hash *, int);
void addEdge(graph_t *, int, int, int);
void destroyGraph(graph_p);
graph_p createGraph(int, graph_type_e);
adjlist_node_p createNode(int, int);
void ResolveProblema(Hash *, char *);
int CheckWord(Hash *, char *, int);
char *LePalavra(FILE *);
FILE *AbreFicheiro(char *, char *);
No *AlocaNo(char *);
void AcrescentaNo(No *, No *);
Hash *AlocaTabela(int);
int Disperse(char *);
void InsereNaTabela(Hash *, Info *, char *);
void PreencheTabelaPalavras(Hash *, Info *, char *);
void EscreveFicheiro(Hash *, char *, int);
void MostraDistribuicao(Hash *, Info *);
void LibertarTabela(int, Hash *);
void LibertarNo(No *);
```

This is my main program:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "pal.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  Hash *tabela;                 /* pointer for a vector of No */
  Info h;
  int example;

  if (argc < 3) {
    printf("usage: %s infile m\n", argv[0]);
    return -1;
  }
  h.num_comp = 0;
  h.numPalavras = 0;
  h.m = MAXLENGTH;
  h.num_pal = (int *)calloc(h.m, sizeof(int));
  tabela = AlocaTabela(h.m);
  PreencheTabelaPalavras(tabela, &h, argv[1]);
  example = h.num_pal[10];

    graph_p undir_graph = createGraph(example, UNDIRECTED);

    fillEdges (undir_graph, tabela, 4);
    /*displayGraph (undir_graph);*/

 EscreveFicheiro(tabela, argv[1], h.m);

  /* shows graphically the distribution of the words in the hash table */

  MostraDistribuicao(tabela, &h);
  printf("\nNumber of diferent words: %d\n", h.numPalavras);
  printf("Size of the biggest list: %d\n", h.max_size);
  printf("Number of empty lists: %d\n", h.empty);

  LibertarTabela(h.m, tabela);
  free(tabela);
  free(h.num_pal);

  return 0;
}
```

This is my makefile:

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-g -c -Wall -std=c99 -ansi -pedantic

hashpal: hash.o pal.o
    $(CC) -g -o hashpal hash.o pal.o


hash.o: hash.c pal.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) hash.c

pal.o: pal.c pal.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) pal.c


etags::
    etags *.h *.c

clean::
    rm -f *.o core a.out hashpal *~
```